# filtering form inputs

Tags: php, sql, forms, input, filter

I have a simple contact form with name, email, a select list, and textarea. In my mailer php script I'm trying to add a simple filter to prevent SQL injection or other forms of hacking.

For example, I'm using

```
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

Is this good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly let me tell you that about 85% of protection methods are done with 2 functions.

- [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)
- [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Firstly if someone sends some data to your site such as `$_POST['name']`, and you wish to use this value back on html side such as `<p>The following string: {$_POST['name']} is invalid</p>` then you should ALWAYS make sure that that value has been through [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), this will protect *most* of XSS Attempts

Next is injection, if the value of `$_POST['name']` is going into your database just make sure that you use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on that value.

that will give you 100% protection from sql injection, but all that means is your db cannot run commands from the user, that dont mean that the text is what it should be.

The functions that you should always use before inserting data into your database are

- **[empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)** or **[isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)**
- **[trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)**
- **[strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)**
- **[preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg_match.php)**
- **[filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php)** and **[filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php)**

This is called **Validation** and is only needed for yout to make sure the data the user is submitting is what you want such as **filter_var** would be used to validate that the email they entered is an email and not just some *blah blah*

What i usually tent do do is to run a clean function to make sure that all imputed data is clean with htmlspecialchars

example:

```
function clean($array)
{
    foreach($array as $key => $val)
    {
        if(is_array($val))
        {
            $array[$key] = clean($val); //Recursive 
        }else
        {
            $array[$key] = htmlspecialchars($val, ENT_QUOTES);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Then do the following to make sure that your safe from XSS:

```
$_GET = clean($_GET);
$_POST = clean($_POST);
```

So if someone tried to submit `<a href='test'>Test</a>` then the value would be converted to `&lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt`

Comment: Excellent explanation! Thank you for the function as well :) Would you think that `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS` is a better alternative to the function or will have the same result?

Comment: No, though **FSSC** is very good, I can vouch for the two other functions as the most effective within PHP.

Answer (score 0):

To test the effectiveness, try attacking your own site with SQL injection attacks. Basically, try passing strings like `' || 1=1` and see if you get an error. If you get an error, or if you get an unexpected result, your site is open to attacks. Otherwise, it is probably working; but to be sure, make sure you do lots of testing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried `'` and I `get &#39;` in my email. So I guess it's effective :)

Comment: This is correct then. The characters you should try are `\``, `'`, `"`, `&`, `=`, and `?`.

Comment: They're all being filtered :) FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS seems to be good :)

Answer (score 0):

The better option is to use the mysqli extensions and prepared statements. However, there does exist the `mysql_real_escape_string()` function which specifically "escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement".

Comment: I see but I'm not sending data to the database but emails

Answer (score 0):

`FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS` does HTML-escape '"<>& and characters with ASCII value less than 32. To have an full equivalent for `htmlspecialchars()`, use `FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS` which is equivalent to calling htmlspecialchars() with ENT_QUOTES set. Using this function should make the use of mysql_real_escape_string() obsolete, but safety first :)

see also: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php for more information.