# Constant FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING is deprecated

Tags: php, filter, sanitization, php-8.1

I have installed PHP 8.1 and I started testing my old project. I have used the filter `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` like so:

```
$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Now I get this error:

> Deprecated: Constant FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING is deprecated

The same happens when I use `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED`:

> Deprecated: Constant FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED is deprecated

What can I replace it with?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

This filter had an unclear purpose. It's difficult to say what exactly it was meant to accomplish or when it should be used. It was also confused with the default string filter, due to its name, when in reality the default string filter is called `FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW`. The PHP community decided that the usage of this filter should not be supported anymore.

The behaviour of this filter was very unintuitive. It removed everything between `<` and the end of the string or until the next `>`. It also removed all `NUL` bytes. Finally, it encoded `'` and `"` into their HTML entities.

If you want to replace it, you have a couple of options:

1. Use the default string filter `FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW` that doesn't do any filtering. This should be used if you had no idea about the behaviour of `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` and you just want to use a default filter that will give you the string value.
2. If you used this filter to protect against XSS vulnerabilities, then replace its usage with [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). Don't call this function on the input data. To protect against XSS you need to encode the output!
3. If you knew exactly what that filter does and you want to create a polyfill, you can do that easily with regex.

   ```
   function filter_string_polyfill(string $string): string
   {
       $str = preg_replace('/\x00|<[^>]*>?/', '', $string);
       return str_replace(["'", '"'], ['&#39;', '&#34;'], $str);
   }
   ```

[Don’t try to sanitize input. Escape output.](https://benhoyt.com/writings/dont-sanitize-do-escape/)

Comment: Note `htmlspecialchars` might not be a one to one replacement. `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` trips tags. `strip_tags` would be useful in that case.

Comment: @LouisCharette If you need one to one replacement, you can use the polyfill I created. `strip_tags` is also not one to one replacement.

Comment: I understand the need to encode the output. However, decision about not filtering the input using FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW is by my oppinion very bad decision. Nobody wants to have a total mess in the database. I am definitelly missing FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING a lot.

Comment: @Dharman, how about `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS` as a replacement for `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`? Alternatively, looping through the [values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794465/filtering-form-inputs/3794543#3794543).

Comment: @motivated It's not an exact replacement because it doesn't remove data as FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING did. But it's ok to use when printing the data out to HTML. Just make sure you are not using this on input values like $_POST or $_GET

Comment: @Dharman, do you mean avoiding `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS` for `$_POST` and/or `$_GET`? What filter should be used with `filter_var`?

Comment: @Motivated Did you read the article linked at the end of my post? You should never use HTML formatting on the input data. HTML formatting should only be used when outputting to HTML. All `FILTER_SANITIZE*` filters are pretty useless and if I were you I would avoid them like fire. If you want to protect your site against XSS, use `htmlspecialchars` for HTML. But of course, you need to know where you output the data and format it accordingly. There's no magic sanitize solutions to protect you from evil.

Comment: @Dharman, I'm confused. Do you mean that I should never sanitize `$_POST` and `$_GET` and instead use `htmlspecialchars` when outputting the results?

Comment: @Motivated Yes, that's exactly what I said. Validate input, format output, and never sanitize (remove parts of data) anything.

Comment: @Dharman, if we are never sanitizing for example `$_GET`, doesn't that potentially introduce a vector to be exploited? As an example, it's suggested [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64967/how-to-properly-validate-data-from-get-or-request-using-wordpress-functions)

Comment: @motivated No, if you are using other proper security measures. You are being very vague in your question. There are lots of attack vectors and they have a proper security fix too. Sanitizing isn't one of them

Comment: Even though the old `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` is a bit weird, it does something resembling `strip_tags`, which was very good to avoid stored XSS. The "Don't sanitize input, escape output" mention is foolish, we don't want to store XSS. Therefore: 1) Sanitize input; 2) Validate input and 3) Escape output, always in that order.

Comment: @royarisse it's foolish to try and sanitize input as you can't avoid all xss this way. Xss happens when you output. Everything before then it's just text.

Comment: IMHO you should do both.  You should sanitize input if you're going to perform backend operations with it (e.g. searching file contents, or database queries). And sanitize the output if you're sending the string back to the frontend/user. Thoughts?

Comment: @royarisse Sanitising or over-validating input leaves you at risk of [the Scunthorpe problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem): once you remove or block content, you can't get it back. Maybe that string you've just "removed HTML tags" from was actually a mathematical equation full of `<` and `>` operators; maybe that line that looked like an HTTP request was actually someone innocently using the word "get" near some links (an actual false positive from mod_security). If you only escape once on output, you solve the security risk without data loss.

Answer (score 58):

The closest constant you can use instead, if you intend to convert your variable in a safe html string, is **FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS**

Comment: This worked for me, so just to clarify for everyone else (because there is a difference): From W3: "The FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING filter removes tags and remove(s) or encode(s) special characters from a string." versus "The FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS filter HTML-escapes special characters."

Answer (score 11):

From [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) you should replace it with `htmlspecialchars()`.

*FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING*

> Strip tags and HTML-encode double and single quotes, optionally strip or encode special characters. Encoding quotes can be disabled by setting FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES. (Deprecated as of PHP 8.1.0, use htmlspecialchars() instead.)

*FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED*

> Alias of "string" filter. (Deprecated as of PHP 8.1.0, use htmlspecialchars() instead.)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I replaced the FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING constant. This way you can also use flags.

I had some PHP backend tests, and they work fine with this method.
Improvements are appreciated.

```
/**
 * @param string $value
 * @param array $flags
 * @return string
 */
private static function sanitizeFilterString($value, array $flags): string
{
    $noQuotes = in_array(FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES, $flags);
    $options = ($noQuotes ? ENT_NOQUOTES : ENT_QUOTES) | ENT_SUBSTITUTE;
    $optionsDecode = ($noQuotes ? ENT_QUOTES : ENT_NOQUOTES) | ENT_SUBSTITUTE;

    // Strip the tags
    $value = strip_tags($value);

    // Run the replacement for FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
    $value = htmlspecialchars($value, $options);

    // Fix that HTML entities are converted to entity numbers instead of entity name (e.g. ' -> &#34; and not ' -> &quote;)
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64083440/use-php-htmlentities-to-convert-special-characters-to-their-entity-number-rather
    $value = str_replace(["&quot;", "&#039;"], ["&#34;", "&#39;"], $value);

    // Decode all entities
    return html_entity_decode($value, $optionsDecode);
}
```

Answer (score -10):

It can easily replaced with this:

```
FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW
```

Comment: It CAN be replaced with that, but the behavior is different. If the FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING was being relied upon to protect against malicious input, switching as you recommend will remove that protection.