# two php files simultaneously

Tags: php, redirect

I was trying to make a website.  [So this is the index.php page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLDD0.png) 
When 'more info' of any of the form is clicked, the user is redirected to a payment.php page, where the user must make the payment. Once the payment is done, the user is redirected to success.php page, which is supposed to [show these 3 lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMxEg.png)  for two seconds and then redirect the user to details.php page. However, for some reason, instead of redirecting to details.php, both details.php and index.php come up simultaneously [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc5St.png). How can I avoid the index file from being there too? I just want to show the details file.

Here is the code of the success page:

```
<?php
include 'index.php';

if(!empty($_GET['tid'] && !empty($_GET['product']))) {
  $GET = filter_var_array($_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

  $tid = $GET['tid'];
  $product = $GET['product'];
} else {
  header('Location: payment.php');
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Thank You</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container mt-4">
  <h2>Thank you for purchasing <?php echo $product; ?></h2>
  <hr>
  <p>Your transaction ID is <?php echo $tid; ?></p>
  <p>Check your email for more info</p>
  <?php header('Refresh: 2; URL=details.php?id='.$customer['id']);?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I feel that this is the most important part of the success.php code:

```
  <?php header('Refresh: 2; URL=details.php?id='.$customer['id']);?>
```

here's the details page:

```
<?php
include 'config/db_connect.php';
include 'config/db.php';
include 'index.php';
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $id_to_delete = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['id_to_delete']);

    $sql = "DELETE FROM customers WHERE id = $id_to_delete";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        header('Location: index.php');
    } else {
        echo 'query error: ' . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
// check GET request id param
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    // escape sql chars
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']);
    // make sql
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id = $id";
    // get the query result
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    // fetch result in array format
    $customer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    //mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php include 'templates/header.php'; ?>
<div class="container center grey-text">
    <?php if ($customer) : ?>
        <h4><?php echo $customer['Job_Type']; ?></h4>
        <p>Contact Number of loan enquirer: <?php echo $customer['Telephone']; ?></p>
        <p>Annual income: <?php echo 12 * $customer['Monthly_salary']; ?></p>
        <p>Existing loan amount: <?php echo $customer['Existing_loan_amount']; ?></p>
        <p>Residential_Type: <?php echo $customer['Residential_Type']; ?></p>
        <p>Job: <?php echo $customer['Job']; ?></p>
        <p>Form submission time: <?php echo date($customer['Form_Submission_Time']); ?></p>
        <!-- DELETE FORM -->
        <form action="details.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="id_to_delete" value="<?php echo $customer['id']; ?>">
            <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" class="btn brand z-depth-0">
        </form>
    <?php else : ?>
        <h5>No such customer exists.</h5>
    <?php endif ?>
</div>
<?php include 'templates/footer.php'; ?>

</html>
```

Comment: Constant [FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69207368/constant-filter-sanitize-string-is-deprecated) is deprecated. Please stop using it.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your details page starts with these three line:

```
include 'config/db_connect.php';
include 'config/db.php';
include 'index.php';
```

As you can see, in the third line, you include `index.php`. My best guess is that that is the reason you see it in the details page.

Comment: the problem is that if I remove include('index.php') then the variables cannot be passed from the index.php to details.php

Comment: I understand, but that's a different problem. You haven't show the content of `index.php` or those variables, so we cannot help you there. Perhaps you could ask a new question? As a hack you could put `ob_start();` in front of the `include('index.php');` line, and `ob_end_clean();` on the line after it. That way you discard any output of `index.php`. See the [Output Control Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php). But this isn't a good permanent solution.

Comment: actually the ob_start and end_clean trick worked and the result seems to be perfectly what I wanted it to be. Can you please tell me why it's not a good permanent solution though?

Comment: @Xin_Naz: It's not a good solution because your code is doing stuff that it doesn't need to do. You code should also not calculate a trajectory to the moon, just because it can, if all you want to do is go to the next town. This wastes computer resources.

Comment: I understand. Thanks nonetheless bro