# Change the text style of header through checkboxes css + php

Tags: php, html, css

I have an assignment to create the web page. One of the points is to make able to change the style of the text through checkboxes. Web programming is not my primary areas, (I am mostly in C#). I don't know how to do it through PHP, as we have started learning recently.

There is my PHP code.

```
    <?php
$firstName = "Yaroslav";
$lastName = "Yatsyk";
$studentID = "101343887";
$checks = [];

$courses = array("COMP1230"=>"Advanced Web Programming", "COMP2129" => "Advanced Object-Oriented Programming", "COMP2130" => "Application Development using Java",
"COMP2138" => "Advanced Database Development","COMP2147" => "System Analysis, Design And Testing", "GSCI1003" => "Statistics");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Assignment 1</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Sending data by GET/POST method">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="author" content="Yaroslav Yatsyk">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="101343887.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            <?php
            echo $firstName . " " . $lastName . " - " . $studentID;
            ?>
        </h1>
        <form action="101343887.php" action="POST">
    <section id="textFiled">
        Name: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $firstName?> " name="name" required>
        <br><br>
        Surname: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $lastName?>" name="surname" required>
        <br><br>
        Student ID: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $studentID?>" name="id" required>
        <br><br>

        Class: <input list = "classes" name="classes" id="classes" required>
        <datalist id="classes">
          <?php
            foreach($courses as $key=>$value){
                echo "<option>".$key."</option>"."<br />";
              }
          ?>
        </datalist>
    </section>
    <br>
    <section id="checkBoxes">
              <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="Strong" value="strong">
              <label for="Strong">Strong</label>

              <br><br>

              <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="Underline" value="underline">
              <label for="Underline">Underline</label>

              <br><br>

              <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="Uppercase" value="uppercase">
              <label for="Uppercase">Uppercase</label>
    </section>
<br><br>
    <section id="radios">
    <input type="radio" name="12ptx" id="12ptx" value="12pt">
              <label for="12ptx">12pt</label>

              <br><br>

              <input type="radio" name="18ptx" id="18ptx" value="18pt">
              <label for="18ptx">18pt</label>

              <br><br>

              <input type="radio" name="24ptx" id="24ptx" value="24pt">
              <label for="24ptx">24pt</label>
    </section>

    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

        <section id="output" style="height: 150px; width: 150px;">
              <h2>

        <?php


if(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'name',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) && filter_input(INPUT_POST,'surname',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) && (
    filter_input(INPUT_POST,'id',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)
)) 
    {
    $firstName = $_POST['name'];
    $lastName = $_POST['surname'];
    $studentID = $_POST['id'];   

    if(isset($_POST['check']) && !empty($_POST['check'])) {
        $checks = $_POST['check'];

        // Add code
       
    }

    
    }


echo $firstName . " " . $lastName . " " . $studentID;

        ?>
</h2>
        
        </section>

        <div>
            <?php
                    if(isset($_POST["classes"])) {
                    $key = $_POST["classes"];
                    }
                    echo $courses[$key];
                
            ?>
        </div>

        <?php

            echo "<hr>";
            echo show_source("101343887.php");
        ?>
        <script src=https://my.gblearn.com/js/loadscript.js></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

There is my CSS code

```
    #textFiled input[type=text] {
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#textFiled input[type=checkbox] {
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Please do not be toxic, or do not put minus scores, as I have just begun learning programming at college, and not all things are understandable. I am willing to be better, but I need professional assistance to approach it.
Thank you

Comment: Anyway I would suggest you can use PHP to generate "style" attributes on the relevant elements, which contain the changes selected in the form. And your checkboxes really ought to have different names, because they're not all one field, or repetitions of the same field. You need to be able to tell exactly which options were ticked. Meanwhile your radio buttons are the opposite - they all need the _same_ name, so that only one of them can be selected. The _value_ will tell the server which one was actually chosen.

Comment: Constant [FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69207368/constant-filter-sanitize-string-is-deprecated) is deprecated. Please stop using it.

Comment: @Dharman we are required to use it

Comment: Who is requiring you to use it? Also, this still doesn't change the fact that you must stop using it. It will be gone from PHP. It's a useless filter

Comment: Our instructor @Dharman

Comment: Now, all is working

Comment: Change your instructor. Change the course. Change the school. I can't believe any teacher would encourage their students to use this filter

Comment: I can not @Dharman, I live in Canada, and I have OSAP, that can be affected.

Comment: At least talk to your instructor and tell them that they should not be using this filter. Show them the post I linked to you. Make them change their mind as they are very wrong to ask you to use it

Comment: How many years of experience do you have with PHP?
@Dharman

Comment: I have 12 years of experience

Comment: Work experience?
@Dharman