# How To Call A Custom Function As A Validator's Parameter For The filter_input() Function?

Tags: php, input, filter

I am tring to create a custom VALIDATOR in the function filter_input().
So far, we got these built-into php:
A.

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST,"$input",FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)
```

B.

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST,"$input",FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

The above 2 VALIDATORS exist. But not this following one:

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST,"$input",FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING)
```

I am aware that, we have the STRING SANITIZER:

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST,"$input",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)
```

But I don't want to sanitize the user's (form inputer's) input. I want to validate it.
So now trying to build my own FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING to use inside the filter_input() function.
I know there are other ways of validating a string but I want to learn how to build my own function or whatever to use it with the filter_input() function. That's the assignment for now.
The following are my two attempts.
I get the following same error on both.

**Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\TEST.php on line 97 and exactly 1 expected in C:\xampp\htdocs\Templates\TEST.php:84 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\TEST.php(97): FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\TEST.php on line ...**

ATTEMPT 1.

```
<?php

$input = 123;

function FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING3($data)
{
    if(is_string($data))
    {
        define("FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING","STRING");
    }
    else
    {
        define("FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING","NO STRING");       
    }   
    return $constant("FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING");
}

echo FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING();

if(!filter_input(INPUT_POST,"$input",FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING))
{
    die("Enter a valid STRING!");
}

?>
```

ATTEMPT 2.

```
<?php

$input = 123;

function FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING($data)
{
    if(is_string($data))
    {
        $constant = define("FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING","STRING");
    }
    else
    {
        $constant = define("FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING","NO STRING");       
    }   
    return $constant("FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING");
}

echo FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING();

if(!filter_input(INPUT_POST,"$input",FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING4))
{
    die("Enter a valid STRING!");
}

?>
```

How to rid this problem ? May I see code samples from you ?

Thank You!

**EDIT:
I have never used CALLBACK before. Regardless, made an attempt but it ain't working.**

```
<form method="POST" name="textfield" id="textfield" action="" required>
<label for="name">Name:</label><br>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" maxlength="255" size="25">
<br>
<button type="reset">Reset!</button>
<br>
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit!</button><br>
</form>

<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='POST')
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    
    function FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING6($data)
    {
        if(is_string($data))
        {
            $value = TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            $value = FALSE;     
        }
        GLOBAL $value;
        return $value;
    }
    
    echo FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING6($name);

    if(!filter_input(INPUT_POST,"name",FILTER_CALLBACK,
    "FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING6"))
    {
        die("Enter a valid STRING!");
    }
}
?>
```

I get error:
**Warning: filter_input(): First argument is expected to be a valid callback in C:\xampp\htdocs\TEST.php on line ...
Enter a valid STRING!**

Can someone show me where I am going wrong ?
A code sample (an edit of mine) would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out `FILTER_CALLBACK` from https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.misc.php for specifying your own custom filter.

Comment: @cOle2, I tried as you suggested. Can you see my original post at the bottom from the section "EDIT" and respond ?

Comment: Folks, I am continuing this new error issue on another thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69758618/warning-filter-input-first-argument-is-expected-to-be-a-valid-callback-in

Comment: Constant [FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69207368/constant-filter-sanitize-string-is-deprecated) is deprecated. Please stop using it.