# Login with Google OAuth2 and PHP: Google_Client::getRefreshToken() always return null

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-people-api

I need to read and write Google contacts with PHP via Google People API.
I connect to a Google account:

```
function get_google_client( array $params ): Google_Client {
    $app_name     = $params['application_name'] ?? 'My App';
    $creds_file   = $params['credentials_file'] ?? 'credentials.json';
    $redirect_uri = $params['redirect_uri'] ?? home_url();
    $access_type  = $params['access_type'] ?? 'offline';
    $scopes       = $params['scopes'] ?? array(
        Google\Service\Oauth2::USERINFO_EMAIL,
        Google\Service\PeopleService::USERINFO_PROFILE,
        Google\Service\PeopleService::CONTACTS,
        Google\Service\PeopleService::CONTACTS_READONLY
    );
    $state        = $params['state'] ?? null;

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName( $app_name );
    $client->setAuthConfig( $creds_file );
    $client->setRedirectUri( $redirect_uri );
    $client->setAccessType( $access_type );
    $client->setScopes( $scopes );
    if ( $state ) {
        $client->setState( $state );
    }

    return $client;
} 

$client = get_google_client( array() );
$token = $_SESSION['google_token'] ?? null;

if ( $token ) {
    $client->setAccessToken( $token );
}

if ( $client->isAccessTokenExpired() ) {
    if ( $client->getRefreshToken() ) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken( $client->getRefreshToken() );
    } else {
        $auth_code = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'code', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

        if ( $auth_code ) {
            $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode( $auth_code );
            $client->setAccessToken( $token );
        }
    }
}
```

Authentication works but token expires after 1 hour so I need to refresh it but `$client->getRefreshToken()` always return null so I can't.

What's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried saving your access token ````token.json```` into a file? Also, if you cannot get a refresh token, you can reset your authentication manually.

I suggest you check the code in the [quickstart page](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/php) and add only the required scopes until you encounter a problem.

Comment: I already tried to save access token in a json file: same problem...

Comment: Does it request authentication manually? Which of the scopes causes the problem? What if you put only the read-only scope ````CONTACTS_READONLY````?

Comment: Constant [FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69207368/constant-filter-sanitize-string-is-deprecated) is deprecated. Please stop using it.

Answer (score 0):

### There could be a number of solutions:

1. Your application does not authenticate manually if the refresh token does not exist. This code segment from the [People API Quickstart | PHP](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/php) should recreate the refresh token.

```
    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
```

2. If, in any chance, the code forces you to re-authenticate manually every hour, there could be some scopes that are restricted, and thus your application needs verification.

> Referring to this [Support Article](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en):
>
> **Sensitive scopes**
>
> Some of the scopes used by the following APIs are considered
> sensitive; see the API documentation or look for the lock icon in the
> Cloud Console. If your app requests sensitive scopes, and doesn't meet
> any of the criteria for an exception (see below), you will need to
> verify that your app follows the API Services User Data Policy.
>
> For a complete list of Google APIs, see [OAuth 2.0 Scopes for Google
> APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#people). To check if scopes are sensitive or restricted, add the
> scopes to your project via the [Google Cloud Console](http://console.cloud.google.com/).