# Error messages don't display under corrensponding input field. Using HTML, PHP

Tags: php, html, contact-form, error-messaging

How do I display corrensponding error message under the input field instantly if user inputs invalid data.
For example, user inputs invalid data into "name" field and error message instantly appears under the name field. Same for "email" and "message" fields.
I'm using next HTML & PHP code:

```
<form method="POST" action="send-email.php">
  
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name*" required>
  <div class="error"><?php echo $nameErr ?></div>

  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email*" required>
  <div class="error"><?php echo $emailErr ?></div>

  <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message*" required></textarea>
  <div class="error"><?php echo $messErr ?></div>

  <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button">Start</button>
  
</form>
```

```
<?php
require "vendor/autoload.php";

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

$nameSanitized = filter_var(trim($_POST['name']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$emailSanitized = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$messageSanitized = filter_var(trim($_POST['message']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$subject = "new message ";

$valid = true;
$emailErr = "";
$nameErr = "";
$messErr = "";

if (!preg_match('/^[\p{Latin}\p{Cyrillic} ]*$/u', $nameSanitized)) {
    $nameErr = "Only Latin and Cyrillic letters and white space allowed in the name field.\n";
    $valid = false;
}

if (empty($nameSanitized) || empty($messageSanitized)) {
    $messErr = "Name and message are required.\n";
    $valid = false;
}

if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/", $emailSanitized)) {
    $emailErr = "Email should contain only letters, numbers, and underscores.\n";
    $valid = false;
}

//only send if all validations passed:
if ($valid == true) {
    try {
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

        $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;

        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
        $mail->Port = 587;

        require_once 'config.php';
        $mail->Username = SMTP_USERNAME;
        $mail->Password = SMTP_PASSWORD;

        $mail->setFrom($emailSanitized, $nameSanitized);
        $mail->addAddress("myemail@gmail.com", "myemail");

        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body =  "Name: $nameSanitized\nEmail: $emailSanitized\n\n$messageSanitized";
        $mail->send();

        header("Location: sent.html");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
} else {
 
    echo $emailErr;
    echo $nameErr;
    echo $messErr;

}
?>
```

I tried different articles.

Comment: Constant [FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69207368/constant-filter-sanitize-string-is-deprecated) is deprecated. Please stop using it.

Answer (score 0):

Put the HTML code in your `else` block

```
} else { ?>
 
<form method="POST" action="send-email.php">
  
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name*" required>
  <div class="error"><?php echo $nameErr ?></div>

  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email*" required>
  <div class="error"><?php echo $emailErr ?></div>

  <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message*" required></textarea>
  <div class="error"><?php echo $messErr ?></div>

  <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button">Start</button>
  
</form>

<?php }
```

Comment: if I'm leaving in HTML and copy form to "else", when I'm pressing "submit" it shows new blank page with form (without style) and error. And if I'm deleting from HTML form and paste it to PHP "else", form isn't displayed

Comment: What is the error?