# How to increment INT up/down based on upvote/downvote form submission?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, forms

I am trying to create a simple forum with upvote/downvote but I can't get the value to submit as either a "1" or "-1", every time I submit a vote it gets submitted as "0" in the "vote" column and I have the vote column set as integer(INT) and use INT during my PHP too, so I don't think that's the issue..

I tried asking ChatGPT but I'm pretty sure that was just making things worse/overly complicated.

Here's my votes table columns:

`| id | username | userID | title | description | uniqid |  url | vote | type | date`

This is my HTML/front-end page:

```
<?php
 // check user session //
 if (isset($_SESSION['usrname'])) {
 $field = "username";
 $value = $_SESSION['usrname'];
 $username = $_SESSION['usrname'];
} else {
 $field = "userID";
 $value = $userID;
 $username = "";
}

// check if the current user has voted the question //
$stmtVoted = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `vote` FROM `votes` WHERE `$field` = :value AND `title` = :title");
$stmtVoted->bindParam(':value', $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmtVoted->bindParam(':title', $fetch['title'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmtVoted->execute();
$vote = $stmtVoted->fetchColumn();

// count the total user votes for the question //
$stmtVotesTotal = $dbh->prepare("SELECT SUM(`vote`) FROM `votes` WHERE `title` = :title");
$stmtVotesTotal->bindParam(':title', $fetch['title'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmtVotesTotal->execute();
$totalVotes = $stmtVotesTotal->fetchColumn();
?>

// vote form with some information about the question like title, description, URL etc //
<div id="votePostFormContainer-<?php echo $fetch['id'];?>" style="float:right;">
  <form class="vote-post-form" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $fetch['uniqid'];?>" name="postUniqid">
    <input type="hidden" value="Question" name="type">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $username;?>" name="username">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $fetch['title'];?>" name="title">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $fetch['question'];?>" name="description">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $fetch['url'];?>" name="url">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $fetch['username'];?>" name="author">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $userID;?>" name="userID">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s');?>" name="date">

    <div style="display:flex;">
      <button type="button" class="vote-up-button" data-vote="up">
        <iconify-icon width="18" height="18" icon="<?php echo $vote == 1 ? 'bxs:upvote' : 'bx:upvote'; ?>"></iconify-icon>
      </button>

      <div class="vote-count" id="voteCount-<?php echo $fetch['uniqid'];?>" style="margin-top:-2px;color:#666;"><small><?php if (empty($totalVotes)) {echo '0';} else {echo $totalVotes;}?></small></div>

      <button type="button" class="vote-down-button" data-vote="down">
          <iconify-icon width="18" height="18" icon="<?php echo $vote == -1 ? 'bxs:downvote' : 'bx:downvote'; ?>"></iconify-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Blog/resources/voteQuestion.js"></script>
```

And here is my voteQuestion.js for handling the submission via ajax, its also meant to handle the vote increment on the front-end but that isn't working since the form submission keeps submitting a "0" into the "vote" column instead of either "1" or "-1".

```
  (function() {
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".vote-up-button, .vote-down-button").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var postUniqid = $(this).siblings('input[name="postUniqid"]').val();
        var voteType = $(this).data('vote'); // "up" or "down"
        var buttonElement = $(this); // Store the button element for later use

        // Map voteType to an integer value (+1 for "up" and -1 for "down")
        var voteValue = (voteType === 'up') ? 1 : -1;

        // Find the vote count element and update it
        var voteCountElement = $("#voteCount-" + postUniqid);
        var currentCount = parseInt(voteCountElement.text()) || 0;
        currentCount += voteValue;
        currentCount = Math.max(currentCount, 0);
        voteCountElement.text(currentCount.toString());

        // Update the icons based on the vote action
        var upvoteIcon = '<iconify-icon width="18" height="18" icon="bxs:upvote"></iconify-icon>';
        var downvoteIcon = '<iconify-icon width="18" height="18" icon="bxs:downvote"></iconify-icon';
        
        if (voteType === 'up') {
            // User upvoted, change the icon to the solid upvote icon
            buttonElement.html(upvoteIcon);
            buttonElement.data('vote', 'remove');
        } else if (voteType === 'down') {
            // User downvoted, change the icon to the solid downvote icon
            buttonElement.html(downvoteIcon);
            buttonElement.data('vote', 'remove');
        } else if (voteType === 'remove') {
            // User wants to remove their vote, change the icon back to outline
            buttonElement.html(voteValue === 1 ? upvoteIcon : downvoteIcon);
            buttonElement.data('vote', voteValue === 1 ? 'up' : 'down');
        }

        // Send the AJAX request to update the vote on the server
        var formData4 = {
            'vote': voteValue, // Send the integer value
            'postUniqid': $("input[name='postUniqid']").val(),
            'title': $("input[name='title']").val(),
            'description': $("input[name='description']").val(),
            'type': $("input[name='type']").val(),
            'url': $("input[name='url']").val(),
            'username': $("input[name='username']").val(),
            'userID': $("input[name='userID']").val(),
            'date': $("input[name='date']").val(),
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Blog/resources/PHP/voteQuestion.php",
            data: formData4,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.hasOwnProperty('voteCount')) {
            // Update the vote count on frontend
            voteCountElement.text(response.voteCount);
            } else {
                console.log("Unexpected response format:", response);
            }

            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log("AJAX error:", error);
            }
        });
    });
});
})();
```

and heres my server-side PHP that handles the actual insert, update, delete rows/votes...

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['vote'])) {
$title = filter_var($_POST['title'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$type = filter_var($_POST['type'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$username = filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$description = filter_var($_POST['description'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$postUniqid = filter_var($_POST['postUniqid'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$url = filter_var($_POST['url'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$date = filter_var($_POST['date'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$userID = filter_var($_POST['userID'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$vote = $_POST['vote'];

// Check if the vote already exists for the given user and post
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `votes` WHERE `username` = :username AND `title` = :title AND `uniqid` = :uniqid");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':uniqid', $postUniqid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();

if ($count > 0) {
    // User has already voted for this post
    // Check the current vote for the user
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `vote` FROM `votes` WHERE `username` = :username AND `title` = :title AND `uniqid` = :uniqid");
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':uniqid', $postUniqid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $currentVote = $stmt->fetchColumn();

    if ($currentVote != $vote) {
        // User wants to switch their vote
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `votes` SET `vote` = :vote WHERE `username` = :username AND `title` = :title AND `uniqid` = :uniqid");
        $stmt->bindParam(':vote', $vote, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':uniqid', $postUniqid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
    } else {
        // User wants to remove their vote
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM `votes` WHERE `username` = :username AND `title` = :title AND `uniqid` = :uniqid");
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':uniqid', $postUniqid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
} else {
    // Insert a new vote
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `votes` (`title`, `type`, `username`, `userID`, `description`, `uniqid`, `url`, `date`, `vote`) VALUES (:title, :type, :username, :userID, :description, :uniqid, :url, :date, :vote)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':type', $type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userID', $userID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':description', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':uniqid', $postUniqid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':url', $url, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':vote', $vote, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
}

$stmtCount = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COALESCE(SUM(`vote`), 0) FROM `votes` WHERE `uniqid` = :postUniqid");
$stmtCount->bindParam(':postUniqid', $postUniqid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmtCount->execute();
$voteCount = (int)$stmtCount->fetchColumn();

$response = array('voteCount' => $voteCount);
} else {
$response = array('error' => 'Invalid request');
}

// Output the response as JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: `I tried asking chatGPT but I'm pretty sure that was just making things worse`...why does that not surprise me. It's a conversation engine, not a programmer :-)

Comment: @ADyson lol I know right but it comes in useful sometimes :')

Comment: Anyway, in the JS code you submit `'vote': voteType` to the server ...`voteType` can be populated with either "up" or "down" as far as I can see. Clearly, neither of these values are integers. But PHP tries to pass the submitted value straight through in the SQL query and into the `vote` column of the database table.

Comment: @DaTZcodie ChatGPT may be useful to experienced programmers, it can provide boilerplate for common operations. It's not useful if you don't know what you're doing to begin with.

Comment: @ADyson Ah yep your right, my bad, I had it set a while ago as either +1 or -1 but looks like something got changed at some point, I have it set now like so: `var voteValue = (voteType === 'up') ? 1 : -1;` but for some reason the total votes still doesnt increment

Comment: `for some reason the total votes still doesnt increment`...well does it now update the individual vote record correctly? And which query are you referring to regarding the total? Is it the `SELECT COALESCE(SUM(`vote`), 0) FROM`... one? The `console.log("Response received:", response);` command should allow you to see the vote count it outputs...is that where you're seeing an unexpected value?

Comment: @ADyson yes it submits the correct vote now as either "1" or "-1", sorry I meant in the front-end, I think it might be because its an integer and by default there is no votes so it just shows empty space but I believe it needs to have at least "0" by default for the increment to work properly, right? EDIT: yeah console shows voteCount:1

Comment: OK well the front-end won't update as a result of an ajax call  unless you specifically write some JavaScript code to alter the page based on the response. Or are you talking about the `voteCountElement.text(currentCount.toString());` line? It would help if you could be a little more specific.

Comment: @ADyson Yes sorry I've updated the JS in the question to how it is now, which has the upvote/downvote icons changing live when clicked, but I just cant get the actual number count to update live when a vote is clicked, for now I've temporarily just added a small `if` statement to the total count in the form between the upvote/downvote icons in the HTML to display "0" if there is no vote

Comment: Well that certainly that PHP code (`if (empty($totalVotes)) {echo '0';}`) is the right way to solve populating it correctly when the page first loads. Obviously your JavaScript only runs after someone has clicked one of the voting buttons. So is the issue now entirely resolved by that, or is there still a problem? I wasn't quite sure, from your comment.

Comment: @ADyson Yeah so like when someone presses either upvote/downvote the number should update on the actual front-end/webpage from "0" to either "1" or "-1", but I have to refresh the page to see the number change. You can see I added `voteCountElement.text(response.voteCount);` to the success callback but I didnt get any further than that unfortunately and it still doesn't work, but yeah evrything else is working fine, like submitting the vote into the database etc is working fine

Comment: Ok. If we do some simple debugging in your JS code, we can see that the `postUniqid` variable is never populated, which thenn means it can't locate the voteCountElement. The reason is because the hidden field containing the postUniqId is not a sibling of the upvote or downvote buttons. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1seLokw6/ . It's fixed by looking at the parent element's siblings instead: https://jsfiddle.net/1seLokw6/1/ . After that I think you may have one or two more little logic issues to work out.

Comment: @ADyson Ok I see thankyou it works good, yeah the logic is a little buggy but that shouldn't be too difficult to fix, thanks for your help I appreciate it

Comment: Constant [FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69207368/constant-filter-sanitize-string-is-deprecated) is deprecated. Please stop using it.

Answer (score -1):

your `$vote` appears to contain only the values `up` and `down`. If you want it to have an integer value instead, I suggest you update your jQuery formData4 object like this.

```
var formData4 = {
   'vote': currentCount,
   'postUniqid': $("input[name='postUniqid']").val(),
   'title': $("input[name='title']").val(),
   'description': $("input[name='description']").val(),
   'type': $("input[name='type']").val(),
   'url': $("input[name='url']").val(),
   'username': $("input[name='username']").val(),
   'userID': $("input[name='userID']").val(),
   'date': $("input[name='date']").val(),
};
```