# What am I doing wrong in my contact form?

Tags: php, jquery

I created a new website, and I have a contact form. This contact form was made using PHP and connecting to the server via SMTP. When trying to send an email it says "Failed to connect" although all the server details are correct. When checking with inspect element I'm getting Error 409:

[image]

When looking into the code 409 inside inspect element, brings me to a line of code in the jquery-3.7.0.min.js:2 saying "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 409 ():

[image]

The website link for the contact form is https://seachallenger.com.pt/contact.html

Can anyone help me?

I connected the PHP file to the hosting company via SMTP.
My PHP File code:

```
<?php
// require 'vendor/autoload.php';



use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';




if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest') {

    try {

        $send = [];

        $name = $_POST['name'];// filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $phone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'phone', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $message = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'message', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


        // Additional headers
        // $headers = "From: hello@seachallenger.com.pt\r\n";
        // $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n";
        // $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

        // $messageBody = "Name: " . $name . "\n";
        // $messageBody .= "Email: " . $email . "\n";
        // $messageBody .= "Phone: " . $phone . "\n\n";
        // $messageBody .= "Message:\n" . $message;



        $messageBody = "<table border=0>";
        $messageBody .= "<tr><td>Name: </td><td>" . $name . "</td></tr>\n";
        $messageBody .= "<tr><td>Email: </td><td>" . $email . "</td></tr>\n";
        $messageBody .= "<tr><td>Phone: </td><td>" . $phone . "</td></tr>\n";
        $messageBody .= "<tr><td>Message: </td><td>" . $message . "</td></tr>\n";
        $messageBody .= "</table>";


        //Create a new PHPMailer instance
        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
        //Enable SMTP debugging
        // SMTP::DEBUG_OFF = off (for production use)
        // SMTP::DEBUG_CLIENT = client messages
        // SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER = client and server messages
        // Host name: mail.seachallenger.com.pt
        // Username: info@seachallenger.com.pt
        // Password: password

        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; //SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;

        //Set the hostname of the mail server
        $mail->Host = 'mail.seachallenger.com.pt';
        $mail->Port = 465;

        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = 'info@seachallenger.com.pt';


        $mail->Password = 'password';

        $mail->setFrom('info@seachallenger.com.pt');

        $mail->addReplyTo($email);


        $mail->addAddress("info@seachallenger.com.pt");


        $mail->Subject = "New email from " . $name;

        if (isset($_POST['action'])) {

            $mail->Subject = "New Newsletter Subscription " . $name;
        }
        //Set the subject line



        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
        $mail->Body = $messageBody;
        // echo $messageBody;
        // exit();
        //Attach an image file
        //$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

        //send the message, check for errors
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            // echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            $send['success'] = false;
            $send['message'] = 'An error occurred while sending the message.';
        } else {
            $send['success'] = true;
            $send['message'] = 'Message sent successfully!';
        }



        echo json_encode($send);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage()]);
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => 'Invalid request']);
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/409

Comment: Does the code work if you test it on your local  machine?

Comment: Yuo should check the webserver log to see why it's returning a 409 error. This is not normal and I doubt it comes from PHP.

Comment: if you want a test SMTP server, you can use https://mailsnag.com or something similar

Comment: Constant [FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69207368/constant-filter-sanitize-string-is-deprecated) is deprecated. Please stop using it.