# Submission of a form will be added as a lead for Bitrix24

Tags: php, forms, get, lead, bitrix

I have a form that collects names, emails, and positions. While my PHP code successfully sends the names and emails to Bitrix as new leads, the position data is not being transmitted.

```
    <?php
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $position = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'position', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
       
    $webhookUrl = 'https://b24-zXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/crm.lead.add.json';
    
    $postData = http_build_query([
        'fields' => [
            'TITLE' => $name,
            'EMAIL' => [['VALUE' => $email, 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK']],
            'POSITION' => [['VALUE' => $position, 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK']],
        ],
        'params' => ["REGISTER_SONET_EVENT" => "Y"]
    ]);
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $webhookUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    
    if ($response === false) {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $response;
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit;
    }
    
    ?>
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
       <title>FORM</title>
     </head>
     <body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br><br>

        <label for="email">E-mail:</label><br>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br><br>

        <label for="position">Position:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="position" name="position"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I wonder how should it sends position value to Bitrix24.

Comment: According to [this post on Bitrix24's site](https://www.bitrix24.eu/about/blogs/bitrix24-tips-and-updates/lead-creation-from-external-services.php), the position key should be `POST`, not `POSITION`.

Comment: I've never used Bitrix24. I simply googled "bitrix24 lead api" to find the answer to your question, which you just as easily could have done. Please make sure you've made the [appropriate amount of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) before asking. If you have other questions/issues, do the research and post a new question with all necessary information.

Comment: Constant [FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69207368/constant-filter-sanitize-string-is-deprecated) is deprecated. Please stop using it.